# How to use shell script variable as groovy variable in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use the VAR_NAME value set in shell script from sh""" """ again outside in groovy steps but I'm getting following error. I only saw questions on how to use groovy variable in shell but not the other way. Thanks in advance.

*groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: VAR_NAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding*

```
pipeline {

    environment {
        VAR_NAME=""
    }



    stages {
        stage('Compute') {
            steps {

                sh """
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set +x

VAR_NAME=10

                """
sh "echo VAR_NAME = $VAR_NAME"
                }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you issue `sh` directive, a new instance of shell (most likely `bash`) is created. As usual Unix processes, it inherits the environment variables of the parent. Your `bash` instance is then running your script. When your script sets an environment variable, the environment of `bash` is updated. Once your script ends, the `bash` process that ran the script is destroyed, and all its environment is destroyed with it.

If you want to use anything that was set by that shell instance, you need to take it in, for example like this:

```
    def script_output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """
         #!/bin/bash
        set -e
        set +x
        VAR_NAME=10
        echo \$VAR_NAME
    """)
    script_output = script_output.trim()
    VAR_NAME = script_output
    echo "VAR_NAME is ${VAR_NAME}"
```

Comment: The `.trim()` turned out to be unexpectedly important, in my case. Even though I wasn't outputting any extra whitespace, I still had to trim in order for my resulting variable to have the value I was expecting.