# Using Environment Variables in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm learning Jenkins pipeline by assembling a Jenkinsfile, where I'm creating new / accessing existing environment variables; some out-of-the-box; some user-defined..

All seems to work but for one user-defined environment variable, named **PYTEST_RESULT**.

I declare it at top of script as a string but then when trying to override this later with a concatenated value, the initial string instead remains.. Cannot figure out why.. Any ideas would be appreciated !

**1. (Updated) minimal reproducible Jenkinsfile example:**

```
// Declare global variables:
def pytestExitCode = ''
def pytestExitCodeDesc = ''
    
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment{
        PROJECT_NAME = "BigTime Web Transformation"
        PYTEST_RESULT = "TBD"
    }

   stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    export pytestExitCode
                    echo "pytestExitCode before being assigned the pytest exit code is: "$pytestExitCode
                '''
                script {
                    pytestExitCode = sh(returnStatus: true, script: 'pytest')
                    echo "Pytest completed with exit code: ${pytestExitCode}"
                }
            }
        }
   }

    post {
        always {
            script {
                switch(pytestExitCode) {
                    case 0:
                        pytestExitCodeDesc = "All tests were collected and passed successfully"
                        break;
                    default:
                        println("Pytest was not a complete success..");
                        break;
                }
                // Prepare environment variable values to pass to email template body:
                env.BUILD_ID=sh(script: 'echo ${BUILD_ID}', returnStdout: true)
                echo env.BUILD_ID
                
                env.PROJECT_NAME=sh(script: 'echo ${PROJECT_NAME}', returnStdout: true)
                echo env.PROJECT_NAME
                
                // This is what doesn't work:
                env.PYTEST_RESULT = "${pytestExitCode} - '${pytestExitCodeDesc}'"
                // The initial value of 'TBD' remains the latest value..
                env.PYTEST_RESULT=sh(script: 'echo ${PYTEST_RESULT}', returnStdout: true)
                echo env.PYTEST_RESULT
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And following can be used as the associated pytest files..

**2. add.py:**

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

**3. test_add.py:**

```
import os
import sys
# Dynamically update path based on jenkins job name, to include parent-most folder for python to recursively search for its build and test scripts:
sys.path.append(os.environ.get('PWD'))
from ops import *
def test_add():
    assert add(3,4) == 7
```

**Latest attempt:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment{
        PROJECT_NAME = "BigTime Web Transformation"
        PYTEST_EXIT_CODE = "TBD"
        PYTEST_RESULT = "TBD"
    }

   stages {
        stage('Test') {
            environment {
                PYTEST_EXIT_CODE = sh(returnStatus: true, script: 'pytest')
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    switch(PYTEST_EXIT_CODE) {
                        case '0':
                            pytestExitCodeDesc = "All tests were collected and passed successfully"                            
                            PYTEST_RESULT = "${PYTEST_EXIT_CODE} - '${pytestExitCodeDesc}'"
                            echo "PYTEST_RESULT in Case 0's section is: ${PYTEST_RESULT}"
                            break;
                        default:
                            pytestExitCodeDesc = "Pytest has no desc as it was not a complete success.."
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }

    post {
        always {
            echo "PYTEST_RESULT in Post's always section is: ${PYTEST_RESULT}"  // This now works..

            script {
                // Prepare environment variable values to pass to email template body:
                env.BUILD_ID=sh(script: 'echo ${BUILD_ID}', returnStdout: true)
                echo env.BUILD_ID
                
                env.PROJECT_NAME=sh(script: 'echo ${PROJECT_NAME}', returnStdout: true)
                echo env.PROJECT_NAME
                
                env.PYTEST_RESULT=sh(script: "echo ${PYTEST_RESULT}", returnStdout: true) // This now works..
                echo env.PYTEST_RESULT // This still pulls in the initialised value..
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate. that's a valid point.. 

I've rewritten my request; replacing the code snippets as a working minimal reproducible example. 

Hope this makes it easier to understand.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62671820/2047614

Comment: Thanks for direction @MaratC. Your link helped for the most part. In the post section, seems I still could not get the final line to receive the updated value but elsewhere in this section it now works.  (For anyone's reference, my updated script is above, named 'Latest attempt')